# How do you describe it when someone suddenly starts to do something with great enthusiasm?

Tags: word-request

How do you describe it when someone suddenly starts to do something with great enthusiasm, not necessarily displaying rational thinking? I need a verb that precedes a more specific infinitive or gerund. Like 'take to doing something'. Please offer a variety of options.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to tell us what the "something" is we might be better able to find the right words.

Answer (score 2):

He plunged headlong into day trading.

She barreled ahead to start  her  company.

He precipitously took up bungee jumping.

Throwing caution to the winds, they ...